# date and time concatenation in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I wanted to get the only the hour of the time and concatenate it with the date. 
here's my query

```
SELECT distinct TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.date + to_char(TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.time ,'HH')
FROM TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS
```

is there any other way to get the hour of the time without turning it into text?

Comment: Why are you storing date and time in a single column. You should store that in a `timestamp` column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` is the operator to add numbers, dates or intervals.

The string concatenation operator in SQL is `||`.

As you are storing date and time in two columns rather then using a single `timestamp` column, I would convert them to a single timestamp value, then apply `to_char()` on the "complete" timestamp:

Adding a `time` to a `date` returns a `timestamp` that can then be formatted as you want:

```
SELECT distinct to_char(TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.date + TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS.time, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH')
FROM TOTALIZER_METER_READINGS
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `EXTRACT` (or the `date_part` function):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(hour FROM current_timestamp);
```

The result type is `double precision`.